# reloadData doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5

i'm trying to update my UITableview but when i call `[tableView reloadData];` the table doens't update, after i scroll the tableview above the name of the cell while be changed. But it's not adding a new row or something like that.

```
-(void)update {
        [tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@" %i", [tableData count]);
}
```

The nslog it's returing 1 when i add a row it's returning 2 but the table is not updating.

```
- (void) refresh:(id)sender {  


    NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlDataUrl] 
                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error:nil];


    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    parser = nil;

    [self setTableData:[results objectForKey:@"items"]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];


}
```

.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Change UITableViewCellStyle
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"descript"]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"detail"]];
```

.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return [tableData count];
}
```

Comment: What does `[self setTableData:]` do and how does `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method look like?

Comment: [self setTableData:] is setting data in the cellforrowathindexpath (detailtext, image, title)

Comment: @Eimantas i edited the message! with cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Couple things to check.  Is the prototype cell identifier in IB named "Cell"?  Is the UITableView delegate and data source set to the class you have above?

Comment: The UItableview is in an viewcontroller and the uitable is connected with delegate en datasource (file owner) @Rob

Comment: Do you have the numberOfSectionsInTableView and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection methods?  You will need to return at least 1 for number of sections and the number of rows you need in that section should be the response of the second method.

Comment: @Rob please check my first message edit.

Comment: Ok, those look good.  You are sure that you have more than one item in tableData?  Also have you put a break point in numberOfSectionsInTableView, tableView:numberOfRowsInSection, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to ensure they are getting called when you call the reloadData?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10196/discussion-between-jones-and-rob)

Comment: Yes i'm loading new data from my JSON feed.
 @Rob

Comment: Ah placed the breakpoints and numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are not getting reloaded

Comment: Sorry I had to step away.  It sounds like you should check again to ensure that your datasource and delegates are correctly wired up.  These methods are called through delegation.  If you don't have the datasource and delegate correctly hooked up in the IB it won't call these methods.

Comment: @Rob Thanks the uitable is returing ''Null'' after a NSlog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every-time I have seen this problem it is a result of the `UITableView` outlet not being connected. As a result the `reloadData` call is sent to `nil`. This is almost certainly what is wrong in this case. This can be easily tested by a simple log statement.

```
-(void)update {
    NSLog(@"tableView is '%@'",tableView);
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@" %i", [tableData count]);
}
```

More likely than not you will see `tableView is (null)` in the console.

*Side note*:
The fact that the tableview populates at all is a sign that the `dataSource` and `delegate` outlets are connected.

Comment: fixed it lol it i forgot the connect the iboutlet     @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Comment: right :-) The tableview is not necessarily nil, but you can test if it's connected with self.tableView = tableView in e.g. cellForRowAtIndexPath