# reloadData() and setting IBOutlets without Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a `UITableView` inside my `UIViewController` programmatically using [this guide on the Speak Objectively Blog](http://speakobjectively.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/swift-simple-tableview-programmatically.html).

However I now have the problem that `.reloadData()` isn't refreshing the view. However if I drag or move inside the `UITableView` the data appears correctly.

[This answer suggests that I haven't set up the outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200525/1037617). To my understanding `IBOutlets` are for connecting elements in the Interface Builder to the code. Please correct me if my understanding here is wrong.

How do I set an outlet if I created the `UITableView` programmatically?

Comment: Where is .reloadData() being called? Do you have a reference for the tableview, please post the snippet of the code where you call the reloadData

Comment: IBOutlet stands for Interface Builder Outlets so NO if you are doing it programmatically you don't need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If self.tableView.reloadData() doesn't work on its own, use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView.reloadData()})
```

or

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {self.tableView.reloadData()}
```

Answer (score 4):

The guide creates a UITableViewController. It has already an instance of UITableView on it, and it is the one you see in screen. There's no need of creating outlets, so that answer is not actually the answer to your problem (but might be somehow related)

What I can imagine is that you are sending the message somewhere else.

As you can see in the [Table View Controller Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/index.html) , you can get your table view by `self.tableView` (or just tableView in swift)

So make sure you are sending the message to `self.tableView.reloadData()`

If it doesn't work, sending part of your code will help us to see better than to imagine where could be the problem ;)